# Google Chrome broke after deleting Virtualbox?

Tags: google-chrome, virtualbox, debian, debian-wheezy

I was trying to update Virtualbox because copy-paste didn't work in between Virtualbox and Debian Wheezy ( my OS ). It had previously before, but I think I upgraded it and it broke in between.

Fairly certain I installed virtualbox via dpkg -i manually with a .deb file and it was 4.1. I removed it through aptitude and then attempted to install virtualbox-4.3.

Through updating aptitude I seemingly broke google-chrome. When I run it through the command line I can see that the "GLX" extension is not there?

```
meder@oskol:~$ google-chrome&
[1] 4636
meder@oskol:~$ [4636:4636:1203/182733:ERROR:nss_util.cc(821)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
[4671:4671:1203/182733:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(328)] glxQueryVersion failed
[4671:4671:1203/182733:ERROR:gl_surface_x11.cc(57)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

Chromium seems to work ok, but I can't use this because Flash doesn't work on it and I've tried to get it to work with pepper flash but to no avail.

Does anyone know how I could've broke it so that I killed the "GLX" extension, assuming this is the problem?

I do remember `rm -r`'ing a `vboxdrv` in `/etc/init.d/` but I'm fairly certain I didn't accidentally kill any other file in that directory.

Also - I never did update virtualbox.

Comment: Start with the basics remove and then install everything again.

Comment: I think it might have to do with it trying to load webGL. Let me try removing / disabling that..

Comment: I removed google chrome, removed virtualbox, reinstalled, nothing is different. Hmm.